# How to call a function in Page.ClientScript properly

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net

There are two things I do not understand too well in this scenario

First, there is a javascript that is in this format

```
function Allocate()
{
    this.Name = $("allocateName");
    this.AddAllocation = $("addAllocation");
    this.setCustom= $("setCustom");
}
... some other initializations here
Allocate.prototype.EnableAllocations = function() {

 this.enableAllAlloactions();
 this.setCustomAllocations();
}
```

This is just an example, so is this some kind of class in Javascript? this is in a file called Allocate.js.

My questions are the following:

If I was to call the EnableAllocations in a `Page.ClientScript.RegisterClientScriptBlock(...);` how would I do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should instance the Allocate object, and call its EnableAllocations function.

```
  var alloc = new Allocate();
  alloc.EnableAllocations;
```

So you can create a string with tha code and pass it using like this:

```
  Page.ClientScript.RegisterClientScriptBlock("key",
     "var alloc = new Allocate();alloc.EnableAllocations;");
```

- NOTE: you can use this.GetType().FullName as key. You shouldn't use the same key for different scripts.

This method is deprecated. Use [ClientScriptManager.RegisterClientScriptBlock](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.clientscriptmanager.registerclientscriptblock.aspx) Method instead (it depends on which version of the framework you're using).

Finally, I don't know which library you're using, but the `$()` comes from some library. So there's a dependency on that library, and also on `allocateName`, `addAllocation` and so on.. whatever they're.